# How to change the background color of the item selected from the list?

Tags: angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
    name: string;
}

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
    { name: 'STWX1' },
    { name: 'STWX2' },
    { name: 'STWX3' },
    { name: 'STWX4' }
];

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div style="display: inline-block; width = 200px; ">
            <ul class="heroes">
                <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)"
                    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
                     <p [style.background-color]="getStyle()">{{hero.name}}</p>
                </li>
           </ul>
       </div>'
   ,
   styles: [...]
})

export class AppComponent  {
 public showStyle: boolean = false;

    name = 'Angular1';
    testRequestId = '3224';
    heroes = HEROES;
    selectedHero: Hero;

    goToDivClick() {
        return HEROES;
    }

    onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
        this.showStyle = true;
        this.selectedHero = hero;
    }

getStyle() {
        if (this.showStyle) {
            return "grey";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the background of the item selected from a list. As per my code above, I have a list and I am trying to call a method getStyle() to change the background color of the selected item to Yellow. As of now, its changing color for all the list items. I am not getting how to specifically change color only for the selectedhero in my example. Can you please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Why don't you just add CSS to your component that addresses the `selected` class you are adding already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<p [style.background-color]="getStyle(hero)">
```

```
    getStyle(hero) {
        if (hero === this.selectedHero) {
            return "grey";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

or

```
<p [style.background-color]="hero===selectedHero ? 'grey' : ''">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked fine. Also, can you please let me know how to keep the div height fixed in this case if even the list grows. I mean when the list grows, instead of div height being extended, I want to show scroll bar.

Comment: Just set the `height` you want and `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` or `overflow-y: auto` if you only want a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: I have my css like this. .container .col {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    border-color : red;
    border-style : ridge;
    overflow: auto;
}

Comment: Did you trx `scroll` instead of `auto`?

Comment: Hard to tell. There is nothing special in Angular2 and this is how it's done in CSS

Comment: I understand. Thank you.