# I want to switch the background after clicking for permanent using Angular

Tags: html, angular, sass

After clicking on each button i want to change their background and remove the background of other for the permanent.
[This is the thing I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8qO5.png)

This is the HTML code :

```
<div class="time-stamp">
  <label for="time" class="fw-bold label-text">Time</label>
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div *ngFor="let time of timeStamp; let idx=index">
      <button type="radio" class="rounded-pill" id="{{idx}}" (click)="addTime('{{idx}}')"> {{time}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
button{
     border: 1px solid #9319FF;
     height: 24px;
     width: 88px;
     padding: 0;
     font-size: 13px;
     margin-right: 26px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     &:hover{
         background-color: #9319FF;
    }
     &:focus{
         background-color: #9319FF !important;
    }
     &:visited{
         background-color: #9319FF !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121765/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-item-selected-from-the-list